# JOIN mysql if else statement

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements

This is an odd conditional statement - and I am not sure if it is possible.

I have a MYSQL QUERY:

```
SELECT 
cute_news.title, cute_news.id, cute_news.avatar, cute_news.category,cute_news.date, cute_fields.YouTubeTN, cute_fields.alternate_title, cute_fields.NewsSource, cute_fields.alternate_url, cute_fields.cf_id 
FROM cute_news, cute_fields 
WHERE 
YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(cute_news.date)) = '2007' AND 
cute_fields.cf_id = cute_news.cf_id AND 
FIND_IN_SET ('10', cute_news.category) 
ORDER BY cute_news.date DESC
```

My question is I want :

```
IF ( cute_fields.cf_id = cute_news.cf_id )THEN
{  SELECT 
cute_news.title, cute_news.id, cute_news.avatar, cute_news.category,cute_news.date, cute_fields.YouTubeTN, cute_fields.alternate_title, cute_fields.NewsSource, cute_fields.alternate_url, cute_fields.cf_id 
FROM cute_news, cute_fields 
WHERE 
YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(cute_news.date)) = '2007' AND 
cute_fields.cf_id = cute_news.cf_id AND 
FIND_IN_SET ('10', cute_news.category) 
ORDER BY cute_news.date DESC }
ELSE {
 SELECT 
cute_news.title, cute_news.id, cute_news.avatar, cute_news.category,cute_news.date 
FROM cute_news 
WHERE 
YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(cute_news.date)) = '2007' AND 
FIND_IN_SET ('10', cute_news.category) 
ORDER BY cute_news.date DESC }
ORDER BY..
```

Having the hardest time to actually execute this.. Maybe it isn't possible.
Thanks in advance NINJAS!

Comment: Can you clarify what the "do this" vs "do that" is?  Is it a separate query, different columns returned, different where etc?  If so, please show BOTH version of the do this/that you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks = just updated.

Comment: As you are using `cute_fields.cf_id = cute_news.cf_id ` in where condition, which basically translates to inner join, you will only get matching records. So your `if` part will always be true. You might want to use `left join`

Comment: yes, using the id's for an inner join. the problem with my database is I have about 500 records that will match the "cf_id" with each other to join the table ( trying to avoid going back and updating all those old records.. )

Comment: Did you have an example I could see ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement clearly, you need `Left Join`. If will give you `NULL` for your `Else` part.

```
SELECT 
cute_news.title, cute_news.id, cute_news.avatar, cute_news.category,cute_news.date, 
cute_fields.YouTubeTN, cute_fields.alternate_title, cute_fields.NewsSource, cute_fields.alternate_url, cute_fields.cf_id 
FROM cute_news n
LEFT JOIN 
cute_fields f
ON f.cf_id = n.cf_id
WHERE 
YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(cute_news.date)) = '2007' AND 
FIND_IN_SET ('10', cute_news.category) 
ORDER BY cute_news.date DESC
```

Comment: Perfecto! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.